# Drawing a triangle in MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, monogame

I'm trying to draw a green 2D triangle in MonoGame using `DrawUserPrimitives`, but I can't seem to get it working. Every approach that I have tried results in either vague errors or nothing being drawn.

This is my latest attempt at drawing a triangle, taken almost completely from a resource that I found on the Internet:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    _vertexPositionColors = new[]
    {
        new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), Color.Green),
        new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(10, 0, 1), Color.Green),
        new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(10, 10, 1), Color.Green)
    };

    _basicEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);
    _basicEffect.World = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(
        0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    EffectTechnique effectTechnique = _basicEffect.Techniques[0];
    EffectPassCollection effectPassCollection = effectTechnique.Passes;

    foreach (EffectPass pass in effectPassCollection)
    {
        pass.Apply();

        GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
            _vertexPositionColors, 0, 1);
    }

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

This results in a empty blue screen without any trace of a triangle.

Comment: Your vertices have z-coordinate `1` but your `zfar` is also `1` (which specifies the background). Thus, nothing will be drawn because the GPU assumes that there is already something in front of the triangles (the background). Either increase `zfar` in `CreateOrthographicOffCenter()` or decrease the positions' z-coordinate. You might also want to consider inverting the vertex order if that does not help. Backface culling might remove triangles if you are looking at their back.

Comment: It was the z-coordinate's fault. I set it to 0 and now it sucessfully shows a triangle. I can't believe i've been stuck on something so small for so long. Thank you.

Comment: However i just noticed that the triangle is white. Do you know why it isn't green like the VertexPositionColor?

Comment: Is lighting disabled and vertex colors enabled in the effect (`_basicEffect.LightingEnabled`, `.VertexColorEnabled`)?

Comment: i just disabled and enabled them, but it doesn't seem like it changed anything.

Comment: You should use _basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes instead of _basicEffect.Techniques. Also, make sure _basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled is set to true. Incredibly useful video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqwfoMjJAO4